# ¿Qué hace la función getoolkit().beep()?

Tags: java

Me gustaría saber para que sirve esta función

`getToolkit().beep();`

¿Qué hace?

Soy nuevo en java y es para un trabajo de la facultad, desde ya muchas gracias!!

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: La documentación de dicho método es bien clara: Emite un sonido dependiendo de la configuración del sistema nativo.

Comment: Lo acabo de utilizar en un código y comprobé lo que no me quedaba claro, muchas gracias!!